# IPython, mutable dict keys, possible insanity

Tags: python, dictionary, ipython

Dict-keys should probably be immutable, but that's not *actually* a requirement. All that's required is that the key can be hashed. What happens if I change the object in such a way that its hash changes after inserting it into my dict? Besides just generally "bad things", I'm getting some extra-unexpected behavior.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self, n):
            self.n = n
        def __hash__(self):
            return self.n

>>> foo = Foo(1)
>>> d = {foo : foo.n}
>>> print(d)
{<__main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 1}
>>> d
{<__main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 1}
```

so far, so good. The time for following rules is over. Let's do something dumb:

```
>>> foo.n += 1
```

Now, I'm running `IPython 5.1.0` (installed via `anaconda`), which is running `Python 3.5.2` (on a Mac? not sure yet which system details are interesting - ask for more info and I'll be happy to add it).

```
>>> print(d)
{<__main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 1}
>>> d
KeyError ...
IPython/core/formatters.py
    print.pretty(obj)
IPython/lib/pretty.py
    return self.type_pprinters[cls](obj, self, cycle)
IPython/lib/pretty.py
    p.pretty(obj[key])
KeyError: <__main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef>
```

This is surprising/confusing to me - if we can correctly `print` the object, why can't `IPython` figure out how to `print` it? It seems like it's trying to look up the key, which of course it can't find because the hash changed, but - why then does `print(d)` work just fine?

Ok, not done being dumb:

```
>>> d[foo] = foo.n
```

Logically thinking - the hash of `foo` changed so it'll not recognize that it "already has this key" - it *doesn't* already have this key. And:

```
>>> print(d)
{__main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 1, __main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 2}
```

but then, asking `IPython` to show:

```
>>> d
{__main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 2, __main__.Foo at 0xdeadbeef: 2}
```

Might be a little hard to see amidst the pointers and dunderscores, but it thinks *BOTH* values in our dictionary are `2`. Based on the stacktrace above, I'm guessing this is because it tries to use the `foo` it has a reference to, and instead of actually looking *at* our dictionary keys, it ...thinks it knows...? And just uses the reference (for our current `foo`, with `foo.n=2`, and it "knows" the values are `foo.n` not "regular integers")? This is probably the most baffling part, and where I would appreciate some understanding.

Final question: is this a bug in IPython (in which case I'll try to file a bug-report) or is the process of using hashable-but-mutable dict keys and changing them and re-adding them to dictionaries "undefined behavior" in Python? It seems pretty well-defined in terms of output from `print(d)`, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The requirement is "hashable", which is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) as *"An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime [...]"*. Thus you're violating the requirement. Your *"hashable-but-mutable"* is an oxymoron.

Comment: We generally try to make IPython work with broken user code, so feel free to file an issue. We may quietly roll our eyes about it, though ;-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann - that might've been what I was looking for - if I'm violating a requirement, then it's fine to get undefined behavior. I didn't realize that was the precise definition of hashable. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasK - eye-rolling encouraged - this was a particularly nitpicky thing that *should* never happen in practice, so I wouldn't worry about it. I was just trying to understand what was the cause of the error/discrepancy to pinpoint what "expected behavior" might be. But as Stefan mentions, once I start messing with object hash values, I lose the ability to have precise expectations about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll put an answer here so we can close this loop:

The beginning of my question said

> "Dict-keys should probably be immutable, but that's not actually a
>   requirement. All that's required is that the key can be hashed."

But, as pointed out by @Stefan Pochmann, that's not precise enough to be accurate. The dict-key must be hashable **and the hash should never change over the object's lifetime**.

That doesn't mean the *object* must be immutable, but it does mean the parts of the object that feed into the hash shouldn't change in such a way that they'd change the output of the `__hash__()` call.

So, when I altered my instance in such a way as to change the hash, I violated the requirement and all bets are off - I can no longer make expectations about how this object will act. The "issue" with IPython then is just a matter of it making valid assumptions about objects that I've violated (the assumptions, not the objects), so it's perfectly understandable for it to error out on me.