# Why do Sets allow multiple of the same object with changing hashCodes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, hashcode

According to my understanding, sets can only have one of each object in them. But I have found the following example where a set has two of the same object

```
class myObject:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def set(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.x

    def __eq__(self, o):
        return self.x == o.x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.x)
```

When I run the following:

```
x = myObject(1)

mySet = {x}

x.set(2)
mySet.add(x)

print(mySet)

x.set(3)

print(mySet)
```

I get the following output:

```
{2, 2}
{3, 3}
```

If I remove the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods it shows there are two objects in the set with the same memory address:

```
{<__main__.myObject object at 0x10e3a10d0>, <__main__.myObject object at 0x10e3a10d0>}
```

I am aware python doesn't allow things like lists to be hashed because the hashcode can change causing a similar error to what is shown above. Why is python allowing this but not for things like lists etc. Surely Python should also have some way of managing changing hashes.

I have tested this same example on java and the same thing happens. Why do these languages allow this?

Comment: it seems hashes in a set are not reevaluated.
which doesn't surprise me. (It would be quite inefficient / magic otherwise)
I think if you want that sets work for you just don't modify anything, that impacts the hash of a set member after adding an item to a set.
If you really want to re-evaluate you might try `mySet = set(list(mySet))` after any 'dangerous/weird' modification of set members. that should help you getting rid of doubles and would fix issues with future insertions

Comment: But then why does python not allow using lists as the hash key if the mutability of lists creates this issue. Surely shouldnt they do the same for custom classes?

Comment: @gelonida: Why would a `set` cache the hashes of its elements?  It’s much more useful to cache on very common types like `str`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython, mutable dict keys, possible insanity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144589/ipython-mutable-dict-keys-possible-insanity)

Answer (score 2):

had a link in here to the docs, which address the hash

What is a hash: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

**What is hashable (IMPORTANT)**: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable

> "An object is hashable if it has a ***hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime...***"

Looking at the set object itself after you have modified x.

```
s = set()
x = myObject(2)
```

Then look at the set member's hash:

[image]

Then:

```
x.set(4)
```

[image]

No change. In fact, if you continue to use that set in other places (e.g. fs = frozenset(s)) you will continue to pass around the old hash.